# "La tua casa" o "casa tua"?

Tags: pronouns, word-order

Yesterday I had an exam  of Italian. I was asked to write a letter, so I wrote it.  After the teacher qualified the exam, he said that writing *la tua casa* was wrong and that the correct way was *casa tua*.

The letter was about setting a date so at the moment when you set the place I asked to the person:

> *Passo alla tua casa o ci vediamo direttamente al concerto?*

He did not explain to me why and I have not found anything on the web about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Now it's more clear :)

Yes, in this case you would say "passo a casa tua" or "da te". "la tua casa" puts the emphasis on the fact that the home is HIS.

Giomasce's answer gives a good difference between the two. See it like "I'll call at your place/home" vs "This is your house"

Comment: it is worth mentioning that the same mechanism used for "casa tua" is used for a young boy/girl's bedroom. It is normal for a child to say "camera mia", "camera tua", and you would say "la mia camera" only to emphatize that it is MY room.

Comment: This question is so interesting that I wish I had more time to answer it. :-) I will add a side question instead: what about *la mia sorella* vs *mia sorella*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Victor, it depends on context.

You say *andiamo a casa tua* but not *andiamo alla tua casa*.

The latter is not wrong, just unusual in most contexts.

Of course there may be many exceptions: For example, as pointed out by egreg's comment below, you can say *andiamo alla tua casa di campagna*, while *andiamo a casa tua **di** campagna* would be very unusual and you should adapt it appropriately.

> *Andiamo a casa tua **in** campagna*

However, you can say both *la tua casa è ben arredata* (a bit more formal) and *casa tua è ben arredata* (a bit more informal).

Comment: Consider also *andiamo alla tua casa di campagna* or *andiamo a casa tua in campagna*.

Comment: Thank you for your counterexample! I changed my answer to elaborate a bit on it.

Comment: But why do we say andiamo a casa tua and not andiamo alla casa tua?

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: I am not entirely sure _why_ the postposition of the possessive adjective. It can happen the same with _scuola_, _cameretta_, etc. Probably you are just stressing out that the house belongs to your friend and not to somebody else (_casa di Luca o casa tua?_). Regarding the omission of the definite article, something analogous happens with relatives, you say "tuo fratello", not "il tuo fratello".

Answer (score 5):

To me the difference sounds more or less like between *house* and *home* in English. *Casa tua* refers to the house as a place of living (like *home* in English), while *la tua casa* refers to the house as a building. There probably exceptions, but this rule seems to be a good way to start.

In your specific case, you probably to indicate the place of living, you do not really care about the building. So I would write:

> Passo a casa tua o ci vediamo direttamente al concerto?

Or also:

> Passo da casa tua o ci vediamo direttamente al concerto?

Answer (score 3):

Victor, as you can see the main difference is due to the presence of the determinative article "la".
It is assumed that a person has a home - *only one* - "casa tua".
Instead, if we refer to a person who owns more than one house, in this case we use the article "la" to differentiate among them. Eg:

- Passo dalla tua casa di via Roma o da quella di piazza Verdi?

or,

- Passo dalla tua casa di campagna o da quella in città?

Please note that "la tua casa" is followed by a preposition, to specify *which one* you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

In usage *andiamo a casa tua* is more commonplace,  *andiamo alla tua casa* is more anachronistic and formal, but not strictly incorrect.  The latter is also more common-place with compound verbs and/or more questioning tone such as:

*dobbiamo andare alla tua casa?*

or

*dove andiamo? alla tua casa?*

There are many linguistic usages which are more and less common, and I would suggest that a discussion with your tutor may well allow for remarking on that point.

It may also be that your tutor marked it down on the tense of *passo*;  I would have tended to go with *Passerò alla tua casa, o ci vediamo direttamente al concerto?* (*Shall I come past your house, or meet you at the concert?*)

Comment: Scusa, @GMasucci, ma “Passerò alla tua casa” suona tutto tranne che italiano idiomatico...

Comment: è possibile che il mio italiano è obsoleto, un poco (molto!:)anacronistico o anche erroneo (scusi, per-favore), perche non l'ho parlato in più di 20 anni, ma da quello che ricordo, ho risposto al meglio delle mie capacità.  Si puoi corrigirmi, sarei felice di ascoltare :)

Comment: Indeed, *passerò alla tua casa*, while not completely ungrammatical is not something an Italian would utter. The present tense for action in a near future is so usual that the future tense would sound weird, and *alla tua casa* seems to want to emphasise something, but I wouldn't see what, and if a friend told me such a sentence, I'd wonder “what about my house?”

Comment: Let's put it this way: if I see *passerò alla tua casa* I'd check if it is a line of a poem, or at least of a song.