# Why is it "casa mia", not "la mia casa"?

Tags: nouns

Most phrases like "il mio cane" for instance have "mio" before the noun. Why is it after it in "casa mia"?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["La tua casa" o "casa tua"?](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/la-tua-casa-o-casa-tua)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The postponed possessive is used only in rare cases: for instance *caro mio* is quite different from *mio caro*

- *caro mio, non si fa così* (exhortation)
- *mio caro, ti scrivo da Milano* (start of a letter)

Similarly, the exclamation is *mamma mia!*, not *mia mamma!*.

The phrase *casa mia* can be translated into English with *my home*, while *la mia casa* would be *my house*. Note the missing article: *casa mia* is not a building that can be distinguished from other ones, it's the place where I live, so it's unique.

The postponed possessive can also appear with the article: *il mio paese* is pretty much the same as *il paese mio*, perhaps the latter shows more affection. Such inversion can also depend from regional usage. However, *casa mia* (without the article) always has the meaning explained above.

Comment: Excellent, and I'd add that "caro mio" implies a rather ironical/commiserative tone.

Answer (score 5):

When the possessive adjective follows the noun it carries an emphatic or emotional meaning*.

As in the following:

> Mamma mia!
>
> Figlio mio!
>
> Andiamo a casa mia!

There is even a very early instance of devotional poetry from Jacopone da Todi (1230 - 1306) with a flipped possessive:

> Figlio, chi dà consiglio
> al cor mio angustiato? (*Il Pianto della Madonna*)

The *al cor mio* being *al mio cuore* has a personal emotional meaning.

However, this does not account for the occurrences of ***casa mia*** where there is seemingly no emphatic or emotional meaning, as in:

> Lui abita vicino *a casa mia*

Perhaps, over time, the emotional sense of ***casa mia*** just became the expected usage, or maybe the emotion of *my home* is always present:

> Casa mia, casa mia, per piccina che tu sia, tu mi sembri una badia.

*Reference: *Routledge Modern Italian Grammar* § 3.7.2

Answer (score 0):

It's like a kind of collocation in English, the meaning is the same, but it would sound strange hearing people say "la mia casa".

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! Actually *la mia casa* is not strange, but it's used in different contexts. To make a similarity with English, *la mia casa* is *my house*, while *casa mia* corresponds to *my home*.