# aggettivi possessivi in Lolita di Nabokov

Tags: grammar, adjectives

ciao,

Lolita comincia così: `Lolita, luce della mia vita, fuoco dei miei lombi. Mio peccato, anima mia. Lo-li-ta.`

che differenza c'è tra `mio` di `mio peccato` che viene attaccato prima del nome e `mia` di `anima mia` che invece viene attaccato dopo il nome?

è sbagliato dire `peccato mio, anima mia` o `mio peccato, mia anima`?

queste due, anzi tre, frasi come sono diverse?

grazie in anticipo.

Comment: Direi che *mio peccato* è “concreto”, mentre “anima mia” è astratto.

Comment: Attenzione, questo non è un testo di Nabokov: a parte “Lolita”, neppure una parola è sua. È l'inizio della traduzione italiana di Giulia Arborio Mella. Per esempio, in inglese è semplicemente “My sin, my soul”.

Comment: In my opinion, it's almost impossible to answer this question. One should track down Ms Arborio Mella and ask her why she phrased those words exactly like that. There are no general rules at work here. A different question might be asked about the position of possessive adjectives, and it has been done more than once, at least [here](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/la-tua-casa-o-casa-tua) and [here](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/why-is-it-casa-mia-not-la-mia-casa).

Comment: In my opinion, this question is not opinion based. Or it is opinion-based as any statement about literary language.

Comment: Quando si parla di letteratura, o di lingua letteraria, non ci può essere la stessa oggettività di altre discipline. Questo non significa che la critica letteraria sia *opinion-based* o, più modestamente, un discorso sulla letteratura non sia possibile, che in letteratura tutto fa brodo e non si possa distinguere la chiacchiera vana da un discorso valido.

Comment: @BakerStreet: La critica letteraria e dintorni sono interessantissime e degnissime, ma non sono l'oggetto di questo sito. Anche la tua risposta è molto interessante, ma a rigore è anch'essa fuori tema perché non vi si parla di grammatica (una delle tag della domanda) o altri aspetti prettamente linguistici.

Comment: Io su questo non sono d'accordo, proprio perché questo è un sito sulla lingua italiana, così si chiama.  Non c'è da nessuna parte scritto che si tratta di un sito di linguistica o di grammatica. E la lingua letteraria non può restare fuori da un sito di lingua italiana,  sarebbe davvero un impoverimento del sito, e un cattivo servizio alla ricchezza della nostra lingua anche letteraria.

Comment: @BakerStreet: Non mi va di polemizzare, anche perché la tua risposta in un altro contesto sarebbe ottima, ma qualcosa _c'è_ scritto. Gli argomenti di domande elencati nell'[Help Center](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) sono tutti più “tecnici”: Word choice and usage, Grammar, Etymology (history of words’ development), Regional differences, Pronunciation (phonetics and phonology, dialectology), Spelling and punctuation, Practical problems you encounter while learning Italian. Ma poco male, in ogni caso.

Comment: Non è una polemica, è solo che trovo riduttivo, ed è un peccato,  in un sito del genere, non poter parlare di come sono usate le parole in un testo letterario, (così come si fa per l'uso nell quotidiano), c'è il tag 'word usage, word choice, e il tag di questo thread è 'adjectives'.  Non vedo perché limitarle al quotidiano. Comunque io sto qui da poco, se 'è una policy consolidata io non lo so, e non sta a me decidere.

Comment: Intendo dire, parlare di 'linguaggio' letterario, non di letteratura in genere, quello sarebbe forse tropo estensivo.

Comment: Se volete continuare questa discussione, si può fare su [meta]. Per quel che vale, io sono più d'accordo con BakerStreet ma non continuiamo oltre in questo spazio per favore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

È una  domanda difficile, e acuta, a cui non si può dare una risposta univoca o assoluta, poiché si tratta di scelte di un traduttore di fronte a un testo sicuramente difficile.

E mi è venuta una risposta-fiume, ma non è facile rispondere in assenza di un contesto.

**Riporto una parte più lunga dell’incipit,** che permette di capire meglio l’insieme del testo.

> Lolita, luce della mia vita, fuoco dei miei lombi. Mio peccato, anima mia. Lo-li-ta: la punta della lingua compie un percorso di tre passi
> sul palato per battere, al terzo, contro i denti. Lo. Li. Ta.
>
> Era Lo, semplicemente Lo al mattino, ritta nel suo metro e
> quarantasette con un calzino solo. Era Lola in pantaloni. Era Dolly a
> scuola. Era Dolores sulla linea tratteggiata dei documenti. Ma tra le
> mie braccia era sempre Lolita.
>
> Una sua simile l’aveva preceduta? Ah sì, certo che sì! E in verità non
> ci sarebbe stata forse nessuna Lolita se un’estate, in un principato
> sul mare, io non avessi amato una certa iniziale fanciulla. Oh,
> quando? Tanti anni prima della nascita di Lolita quanti erano quelli
> che avevo io quell’estate.
>
> Potete sempre contare su un assassino per una prosa ornata. Signori
> della giuria, il reperto numero uno è ciò che invidiarono i serafini,
> i male informati, ingenui serafini dalle nobili ali. Guardate questo
> intrico di spine. (1)

Come si vede è un tono alto e tragico, anche se già in questo incipit
si possono vedere variazioni di registro.

Alcune interessanti osservazioni sono in questo link:

https://lemuseinquiete.it/lolita-uno-scandalo-di-talento/

Come osservato nell’articolo del link, nel primo paragrafo dell’incipit c’è una evidente componente lirica della narrazione, in senso stretto, per uso di allitterazioni e di omofonie, come nella ripetizione delle *L*, o delle *T*, che conferiscono musicalità al periodo.

E, in generale, il tono del romanzo è pieno di pathos, anche se, come sottolinea l’autore nel link, è un tono che può assumere vari registri.
Ad esempio, il secondo paragrafo, sembra far virare il tono verso un registro più quotidiano, per poi riprendere il tono tragico e alto nei paragrafi successivi, dove si parla addirittura di *serafini* e di *ali*, e a cui aggiunge drammaticità l’allusione alla presenza di una *giuria*.

Ricordiamo comunque che nel romazo parla un un professore di letteratura, è la voce narrante del romanzo, il quale si trova in una situazione estrema, davanti a un a giuria di un tribunale che lo deve condannare per omicidio.

E il protagonista parla esplicitamente di “prosa ornata” di un “assassino”, e immagino che questa coesistenza/scontro di istanze permei la prosa  del romanzo e ponga al traduttore non facili scelte stilistiche.

Tutto questo per immaginare le difficoltà poste a un traduttore nel rendere un testo e arrivare  alla **domanda posta da theWoodPecker**

> che differenza c'è tra `mio` di `mio peccato` che è viene attaccato
> prima del nome e `mia` di `anima mia` che invece è viene attaccato
> dopo il nome?
>
> è sbagliato dire `peccato mio, anima mia` o `mio peccato, mia anima`?

Dal punto di vista dell’italiano ognuna di queste scelte sarebbe legittima e corretta.
Si possono solo fare osservazioni sul diverso effetto che possono generare, a seconda di dove si collochino gli aggettivi *mia*  e *mio* (forse *peccato mio* suonerebbe un po' bizzarro, ma comunque legittimo).

Da un punto di vista generale direi che l’aggettivo *mio-mia* posto dopo il nome dà maggiore enfasi, e spesso  si usa nei vocativi *tesoro mio*, *bella mia* e simili, a un compagno o a un figlio in genere non si dice *mio tesoro*.

Nel caso di Lolita, mettendo a confronto la frase in inglese e la traduzione italiana:

> *Lolita, light of my life, fire of my loins. My sin, my soul. Lo-lee-ta:*

> *Lolita, luce della mia vita, fuoco dei miei lombi. Mio peccato, anima mia. Lo-li-ta:*

Come detto sopra, c'è un evidente timbro lirico, e alto. Dal punto di vista delle allitterzioni, il traduttore è stato fortunato con le allitterazioni delle *L* (*Lolita, lombi, luce*), mentre la fortuna cessa nell'ultima frase dove l'allitterazione delle *S* in inglese (*soul, sin*)si perde.

Quindi, credo che il traduttore abbia scelto di mettere *mia* dopo *anima* per dare un tono più tragico e poetico,  e anche perché così si crea un *chiasmo* (lo scambio di posizione  tra i due aggettici *mio-mia*) che dà anch'esso un suono più poetico e l'dea (così mi pare) di un crescendo.

Scrivendo *mio tesoro, mia anima* e persa l'allitterzione delle *S*, il tono sarebbe divenuto più prosaico e dimesso.

Ho poi notato che questa traduzione di Giulia Arborio Mella, per Adelphi, è uguale alla traduzione precedente per Mondadori, quindi evidentemente la traduttrice ha accettato e ha trovato buona quella precedente.

Naturalmente queste sono considerazioni soggettive, mie, e un'altra persona ci può vedere altre cose. Ma resta fermo che dire *mia anima* o *anima mia* suona diversamente.

Insomma, si tratta di una domanda sull’italiano non nel senso grammaticale o di correttezza, ma dell’uso flessibile e infinito della lingua, usata in modi diversi a seconda di quello che si desidera  esprimere.

---

(1)  È sempre la stessa traduzione di Adelphi di Giulia Arborio Mella.

Comment: Non avevo notato che esistono due traduzioni, grazie. Se sono corrette [queste trascrizioni](https://it.wikiquote.org/wiki/Vladimir_Nabokov#Incipit_2), la povera Dolores ha perso 11 centimetri passando da Bruno Oddera a Giulia Arborio Mella. (È corretta la traduzione più recente: nell'originale erano 4 piedi e 10 pollici.)

Comment: Grazie a te dell'informazione. Io nemmeno mi ricordo quant'è un pollice.

Comment: grazie! honestamente non mi aspettavo una risposta così complicata. questo mi fa venire in mente 'Richard Feynman on "Why" Questions' e tu sei il Feynman e io sono il povero intervistatore!

Comment: E magari! Troppo onore! Grazie a te.